# php class in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php file where I have an array with some data in classes like this: (in javascript)

```
array = [
     {engine: "V6",
     capacity: 2.5,
     hp: 300
     }]
```

I tried to put this into a php file but it gave me 500 error

```
$array = [{engine => "V6",
     capacity=> 2.5,
     hp=> 300}];
```

I think I may be doing something wrong over here, could someone confirm?

Comment: you need quotes around the key, rtm: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: You have tons of syntax errors  and your development box is not configured to display [the error messages](https://3v4l.org/gDVGX), thus you get a 500 status code. Where exactly do you intend to use classes in either snippet?

Comment: @Eon please accept the other answer with much more details and less confussion. Mine does not make sense, I didn't read the question carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just translate JavaScript code into PHP without understanding the syntax of both languages.

In JavaScript, this creates an array containing an object:

```js
var array = [
  {
     engine: "V6",
     capacity: 2.5,
     hp: 300
  }
]
```

In PHP, the common equivalent would be an array containing another (associative) array, which would be written like this:

```php
$array = [
  [
     'engine' => "V6",
     'capacity' => 2.5,
     'hp' => 300
  ]
];
```

As an aside, since it's been mentioned elsewhere on this page, you could also write the same thing in JSON like this:

```json
[
  {
     "engine": "V6",
     "capacity": 2.5,
     "hp": 300
  }
]
```

If you called `JSON.stringify(array)` in JavaScript, or `json_encode($array)` in PHP, that's how the JSON string you'd get would look.

The JSON looks very similar to the JavaScript, because JSON's syntax was based on JavaScript's. In fact, the above would be valid JavaScript code, and you can use (arguably, *abuse*) `json_encode` as a way to generate JavaScript code using PHP.

Note that none of these contains any kind of "class" - a class is a way of defining a *type* of object, from which you want to make several instances.

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing PHP with JSOL or JSON. PHP doesn't read JSOL nor JSON natively.

```
<?php
$array = [
    [
        'engine' => 'V6',
        'capacity' => 2.5,
        'hp' => 300
    ],
];

echo json_encode($array);
```

See https://3v4l.org/5b9V1

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225718/discussion-on-answer-by-daniel-w-php-class-in-an-array).